# Word boundaries change when I edit a *.sh file

Tags: vim

I am using gVim 7.4 for Windows.

If I have the text `firstWord.secondWord` in a *.txt file and while in normal mode enter `*`, it will highlight only `firstword`.

But if I do that while in a *.sh file, it will highlight the entire `firstWord.secondWord` string.

I don't like this behavior.  I want it to always work like it does in a *.txt file.

I assumed this is caused by the `sh.vim` file in the `ftplugin`directory, but can't find anything in there that would do that.  My `sh.vim` file is identical to the one found at http://dwsharp.users.sourceforge.net/vim/ftplugin/sh.vim

How do I make it so that *.sh files don't have different word boundaries than *.txt files?

Comment: You can give :set iskeyword to check what are the characters included for a word boundary. You can try in shell files, the following command `:set iskeyword-=.` to remove dot from that. After giving this command, try w,b, or * and check it works or not. If that works, let me know.

Comment: Furthermore, try `:verbose set isk?` -- it will tell you the file that last set it.

Comment: There will be a default ftplugin under a path similar to /usr/bin/vim/vim74/plugin. Check that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the [`'iskeyword'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'iskeyword') option.

This is the default value of `'iskeyword'` for a *.txt buffer:

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
```

And this is the default value for a *.sh buffer:

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,.
```

You can manually remove the extra dot from the option value when in a *.sh buffer by running the following:

```
setlocal iskeyword-=.
```

For a permanent solution, you can add the following to your vimrc:

```
au! BufRead *.sh setlocal iskeyword-=.
```

---

I believe I've tracked down the source of this idiosyncrasy. On my system, I have the following code in lines 19-28 of `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/sh.vim`:

```
" AFAICT "." should be considered part of the iskeyword.  Using iskeywords in
" syntax is dicey, so the following code permits the user to
"  g:sh_isk set to a string     : specify iskeyword.
"  g:sh_noisk exists            : don't change iskeyword
"  g:sh_noisk does not exist    : (default) append "." to iskeyword
if exists("g:sh_isk") && type(g:sh_isk) == 1  " user specifying iskeyword
    exe "setl isk=".g:sh_isk
elseif !exists("g:sh_noisk")                  " optionally prevent appending '.' to iskeyword
    setl isk+=.
endif
```

So it looks like the syntax file is the culprit, and it provides a couple of alternatives for overriding its tampering of the `'iskeyword'` option.

For example, to use the `g:sh_noisk` global variable, add this to your vimrc:

```
let g:sh_noisk = 1
```

Comment: The sh.vim ftplugin used by the OP doesn't set 'iskeyword' though. It must be coming from somewhere else.

Comment: Ah, good spot. It shouldn't really be doing that, as I guess the author is aware.

Comment: What do I need to do to set the g:sh_noisk that the syntax/sh.vim is keying off of?

Comment: Note, recent Vims support the `:syn iskeyword` extension, so modifying 'iskeyword' setting in a syntax script is deprecated (and also is not done anymore in syntax/sh.vim if I read the shell syntax file from the vim/vim repository correctly)